# list item highlighted but not the entire row

Tags: html, css

My current [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d63y4bxc/36/) is working fine apart from one thing. When I hover over the button I see the list displayed. Then when I hover over a list item the background changes colour which is all fine. However when the list item changes colour there is almost a box to the left of the item which is not highlighted and can't seem to get rid of it?

```
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #9FACEC;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
 }

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
 }

.dropdown-content li {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content li:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #4C66E9;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default most of `HTML tags` has some default styling, same is here in `ul tag` and that's the reason that when you hover `li tags` the `left-side` is not `highlighted`.

**Default ul styling,**

```
ul{
display: block;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-top: 1em;
margin-bottom: 1 em;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $region = $('#regionList');
  $region.append('<li id="Europe">Europe</li>');
  $region.append('<li id="Japan">Japan</li>');
  $region.append('<li id="North America">North America</a></li>');

  $("#regionList li").click(function() {
    alert('Clicked list. ' + this.id);
  });

})
```

```css
    /* Dropdown Button */

    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #9FACEC;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
    }

    /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    ul {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
    }

    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    /* Links inside the dropdown */

    .dropdown-content li {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

    .dropdown-content li:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }

    /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }

    /* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #4C66E9;
    }

    .selected {
      background: #FF00FF;
    }

/*Add this*/
ul{
  padding-left:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Regions</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul id="regionList"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you need to add ul tag and set padding-left to 0px. You can add padding-left in li tag to have some spacing before texts.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you. i believe you are looking to remove ui margin. you can do that using

```css
ul{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe below approach solves your problem. It was caused by `ul` element having default padding. I also added `box-sizing: border-box` to list elements, so padding won't make `li` elements stick out of `ul`.

I added explanation below snippet.

#### Solution key part

```
.dropdown-content #regionList {
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown-content li {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
```

#### Snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $region = $('#regionList');
  $region.append('<li id="Europe">Europe</li>');
  $region.append('<li id="Japan">Japan</li>');
  $region.append('<li id="North America">North America</a></li>');

  $("#regionList li").click(function() {
    alert('Clicked list. ' + this.id);
  });

})
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #9FACEC;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content #regionList {
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #4C66E9;
}

.selected {
  background: #FF00FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Regions</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul id="regionList"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Explanation

Problem is caused by browser's default CSS rules, which are for Chrome:

```
ul, menu, dir {
   display: block;
   list-style-type: disc;
   -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
   -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
   -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
   -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
   -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
```

You can see more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp).

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct. I just wanted to explain what's going on.

Your user agent stylesheet contains `-webkit-padding-start: 40px;` for `ul` elements.

[image]

Represented here in green.

[image]

As other answers said, override the `padding` style for `ul` elements set by your user agent stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `padding 0` to your **regionList**

```
#regionList{
  padding : 0;
}
```